# How can I find and display next and previous Wednesday in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to find date of **previous Wednesday** in 'YYYY-MM-DD" format given date string = 'YYYY-MM-DD". Exclusive of today being Wednesday.

I also want to find date of **next Wednesday** in 'YYYY-MM-DD" format given date string = 'YYYY-MM-DD". Exclusive of today being Wednesday.

```js
date_Event = '2022-10-05';

function prevWed() {
    const str_1 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_1.split('-');
    const date_1 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +(day - 7));
    alert(date_1.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // 2022-09-21 FINE!
}

function nextWed() {
    const str_2 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_2.split('-');

    // this is OK, as long as today = "3" but I need the next Wed. regardless of today
    const date_2 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +(day + 7));
    alert(date_2.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // 2023-06-14  COMPLETELY WRONG!
}

prevWed();
nextWed();
```

Comment: What’s the question/problem?

Comment: The date produced by  nextWed() is completely wrong. I need next Wed. And '2022-11-26' is also wrong.

Comment: Nothing in the code calculates the actual Wednesday. It just a week forward and a week backwards from an arbitrary date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `+(day + 7)`. The `day` is a string, let's say its `"05"`, while `("05" + 7)` resolves into `"057"` and `+"057"` is `57`; You need to convert the `day` into number first and then do the addition without the parenthesis: `+day + 7`

```js
date_Event = '2022-10-05';

function prevWed() {
    const str_1 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_1.split('-');
    const date_1 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +day - 7);
    alert(date_1.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // 2022-09-21 FINE!
}

function nextWed() {
    const str_2 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_2.split('-');

    // this is OK, as long as today = "3" but I need the next Wed. regardless of today
    const date_2 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +day + 7);
    alert(date_2.toISOString().split('T')[0]); // 2023-06-14  COMPLETELY WRONG!
}

prevWed();
nextWed();
```

If you want the prev and next Wednesday(today excluded), you can calculate the distance days instead of hard coding `7` and add/subtract it to `day`.

```js
date_Event = '2022-10-05';

// calculate the distance towards Wendesday
const dist = (new Date(date_Event).getDay() - 3 + 7) % 7;

function prevWed() {
    const str_1 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_1.split('-');
    const date_1 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +day - (dist || 7));
    alert(date_1.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
}

function nextWed() {
    const str_2 = date_Event;
    const [year, month, day] = str_2.split('-');
    const date_2 = new Date(+year, month - 1, +day + (7 - dist || 7));
    alert(date_2.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
}

prevWed();
nextWed();
```

Comment: An instructive and useful answer. Doesn't show next / previous Wed. But I appreciate it and will use it.

Comment: The `nextWed()` show "12-10-2022" which is the next Wednesday of 05-10-2022, what is the problem?